# How to base64 encode a string in vyper?

Tags: vyper

I have a string that looks like this:

```py
    name: public(constant(String[25])) = "Mood NFT"
    .
    .
    .
    image_uri: String[1024] = self.happy_svg_uri
    metadata: String[1206] = concat('{"name":', name, '", "description":"An NFT that reflects the mood of the owner, 100% on Chain!", "attributes": [{"trait_type": "moodiness", "value": 100}], "image":"', image_uri, '"}')
```

An I would like to convert it to a base64 encoded URI as a string. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no current workaround to return a simple string. That's why snekmate had to choose the path in the repo.

[You can see the underlying reason here](https://github.com/pcaversaccio/snekmate/blob/main/src/utils/Base64.vy#L48):

```
@notice Due to the Vyper design with fixed-size
            string parameters, string concatenations
            with itself in a loop can lead to length
            mismatches (the underlying issue is that
            Vyper does not support a mutable `Bytes`
            type). To circumvent this issue, we choose
            a dynamic array as the return type.
```

TL;DR: bytes are immutable in Vyper and do not yet have a mutable Bytes builder. That's why string/bytes manipulation is still a bit awkward in Vyper. To work around either build a converter using Vyper/Solidity or simply use the base64 encoding in Solidity directly.

From - [pcaversaccio](https://twitter.com/pcaversaccio)

Answer (score 0):

[Snekmate library](https://github.com/pcaversaccio/snekmate) has the [base64 encode function](https://github.com/pcaversaccio/snekmate/blob/main/src/utils/Base64.vy#L44) you are looking for.

```py
@external
@pure
def encode(data: Bytes[_DATA_INPUT_BOUND], base64_url: bool) -> DynArray[String[4], _DATA_OUTPUT_BOUND]:
    """
    @dev Encodes a `Bytes` array using the Base64
         binary-to-text encoding scheme.
```

Comment: Yep! I started with this. But the output is a DynArray. How would I then convert that to a string?

Comment: My suggestion is that you join [Vyper Discord](https://discord.gg/3dQmHWKZ) and ask Pascal Marco Caversaccio (pcaversaccio) directly.